# OWASP and ADFS 2.0

Tags: asp.net, .net, single-sign-on, adfs2.0, owasp

Is there a security resource / Blog post which demonstrates the goodness of  ADFS 2.0(or general SSO) with the [OWASP - Top 10 list of vulnerabilities](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-Main)?

There are few good resources for ASP .NET (the best one from [Troy Hunt](http://www.troyhunt.com/2011/12/free-ebook-owasp-top-10-for-net.html)). But none of them speaks about ADFS 2.0. Is there any value add with ADFS 2.0 w.r.t to OWASP (Definitely there are !!)  ? A constructive discussion will also be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to talk to Gunnar Peterson (search for 1raindrop). He's the SSO/SAML go to guy. Troy is also good value and is definitely aligned with the Microsoft stack.

The Top 10 methodology is about what researchers found the year *prior* to publication (so OWASP Top 10 2007 was a summary of 2006 weaknesses). For better or worse, researchers don't often come across enterprise applications, stacks or core technologies, such as ADFS.  Those that do are paid to look at them, and unfortunately, that usually entails a NDA.

A better approach is the one I'm adopting for the Application Security Verification Standard, and the OWASP Developer Guide - is to provide builders with building assistance, so a positive, verifiable set of steps you should take to protect yourself.

The Top 10 is a great education piece to get discussions started, but as I wrote in the introduction to the Top 10 2007, The Top 10 2007 (and all of them really) are not standards! Do not use them as such.

Jim Manico is working on a cheat sheet series with a zillion authors. If you have an interest in contributing to OWASP, maybe consider an ADFS or SSO cheat sheet?

thanks,
Andrew